# Akka - resending the "breaking" message

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

In the official [akka 2.0.4 docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.4/scala/actors.html#Restart_Hooks) it says:

> An actor restart replaces only the actual actor object; the contents of the mailbox is unaffected by the restart,
>   so processing of messages will resume after the postRestart hook returns. The message that triggered the
>   exception will not be received again. Any message sent to an actor while it is being restarted will be queued to its
>   mailbox as usual.

Let's say I have a message that caused my actor to restart. It isn't in the mailbox anymore, so it won't be processed by the actor that will take it's place. If I want this message to be processed by the actor anyways (assuming the order doesn't matter in that case), would it be a bad idea for the actor to send the message to themself on restart?

Some (pseudo)code to show what I mean:

```
class ResendingActor extends Actor {
  var curMessage: Option[MyMessage] = None
  def receive = {
    case MyMessage(x) => {
      curMessage = Some(MyMessage(x))
      /* processing */
      curMessage = None
    }
  }
  override def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]) {
    curMessage match {
      case Some(x) => self ! x
      case None => ;
    }
  }
}
```

This way the message that wasn't processed by the actor before it got restarted is pushed to the end of the queue for the new actor.

**So my question is:** Is there any reason I shouldn't be doing this?

The only thing I can think of is that if the message is for some reason malformed, it will never leave the system and cause the actor to be restarted regularly...

Comment: You are right in your last assumption, redelivering the same message over and over is one of the problems, known as a [poison message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703179(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Assuming your error handling is complete enough that any such message would be unexpected (and not a known edge case), I think the better solution is to log the message so it can be manually inspected, and not attempt to re-process it.  Otherwise you should be able to handle the message without crashing the actor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto resend message after actor is restarted by supervisor strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986854/howto-resend-message-after-actor-is-restarted-by-supervisor-strategy)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You already get the failing message in preRestart (see: message: Option[Any]) so no need to stash it away yourself. And yes, it is perfectly fine to re-send it to yourself, but beware of infinite restarts in combination with this since you'll most likely end up with a message that will never be discarded.

Comment: As long as your have set the MaxNrOfRetries you shouldn't get infinite restarts right?

Comment: Can the message be forwarded in preStart in order to preserve the original sender?

Comment: @jpierson yes you can, since the `sender` is preserved in the `context` of the actor. (I had the same question)